# XML special character escape not working

Tags: c#, xml, special-characters

I'm trying to use the "!" special character in my C# class but my xml doesn't result in this  "!MovieName" instead it results in " _x0021_MovieName "
I have tried to &#x21 ; and also use CDATA but they dont work. They turn into a string of more *x0021* (an example) types for each special character.

```
public class Movie
{
  [XmlElement("!MovieName")]
  public string Title
  { get; set; }

  [XmlElement("MovieRating")]
  public float Rating
  { get; set; }

  [XmlElement("MovieReleaseDate")]
  public DateTime ReleaseDate
  { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An XML element name cannot begin with a `!` which is why it's being replaced.

You should be able to start with:

1. Any letter
2. Underscore `_`
3. Colon `:`

See the [XML Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) for more information, or more specifically the section on [NameStartChar](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar).

Answer (score 1):

It's illegal to have a `!` as the opening character of a tag in XML. You'll just have to use a different naming strategy.